# Memory leaks in Netty: -Dio.netty.noResourceLeakDetection: false

Tags: java, netbeans, memory-leaks, netty

I am getting the following debugging output:

```
DEBUG {ResourceLeakDetector} -Dio.netty.noResourceLeakDetection: false
```

but I would like to find out more about the leak so I changed the arguments of run profile in Netbeans (JVM arguments) with the following options:

```
-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=advanced 

-Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=2 [1]
```

However, there's been no change in the output. Any hints on how I can better debug what I understand being a memory leak caused by a ByteBuf[2][3]?

[1] - https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/2035

[2] - https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1397

[3] - https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Reference-counted-objects

Comment: As i know, if you are enable leak detection, you will see errors in your log in case of GC will collect the buffer that isn't released. In other cases you output will not be changed:

http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

Comment: I've tried setting the noResourceLeakDetection flag to true but with visible effect on the output

Comment: Maybe you don't have unreleased buffers?
Did you try to remove one of release() methods?

Comment: What is your Netty version? It seems like you are using an old version. Please try again with the latest stable version (4.0.25.Final as of now)